# Android Volley Double Post

Tags: android, android-volley

It runs twice; It should run only once. I tried with

`_urlWebService = vars.ipServer.concat("/ws/disponibilidadTicket");`

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, _urlWebService, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONArray clientes;

                    if(response.getBoolean("status"))
                    {


                    }

                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },

        new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder
                            .setMessage("Error de conexión, sin respuesta del servidor.")
                            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                {
                                }
                            }).show();
                }

                else

                if (error instanceof NoConnectionError)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder
                            .setMessage("Por favor, conectese a la red.")
                            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                {
                                }
                            }).show();
                }

                else

                if (error instanceof AuthFailureError)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder
                            .setMessage("Error de autentificación en la red, favor contacte a su proveedor de servicios.")
                            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                {
                                }
                            }).show();
                }

                else

                if (error instanceof ServerError)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder
                            .setMessage("Error server, sin respuesta del servidor.")
                            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                {
                                }
                            }).show();
                }

                else

                if (error instanceof NetworkError)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder
                            .setMessage("Error de red, contacte a su proveedor de servicios.")
                            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                {
                                }
                            }).show();
                }

                else

                if (error instanceof ParseError)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder
                            .setMessage("Error de conversión Parser, contacte a su proveedor de servicios.")
                            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                {
                                }
                            }).show();
                }

            }

        })
{
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap <String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        headers.put("WWW-Authenticate", "xBasic realm=".concat(""));
        headers.put("MyToken",sharedPreferences.getString("MyTokenAPI"));
        return headers;
    }
};

ControllerSingleton.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jsonObjReq, "");
jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
 }
```

and yet it runs twice. Someone knows how to treat this problem as it should run only once.

Comment: Show complete code.

Comment: complete code pls

Comment: See it code Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending 1 to the retryPolicy try passing -1 show that your code is called only once.Something like this:-

```
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Hope , it solves your problem.